# Pre-processing packet data

Tags: python, preprocessing

I am confused about how to pre-processed packet data. Does anybody have an idea of how to encode network ports and IP addresses? My goal is to model the data in a such way that I will get a good accuracy for my model.
[image]

Comment: if treated as text, then bag of words perhaps

Comment: Could you give me a bit more of explanations?

Comment: see [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)

Comment: I need to converted it into numbers somehow.. I do not think the bag method is going to work. Thanks anyway.